# interface & inheritance

Tags: c#, oop, interface, inheritance

C#, VS 2008
I have 4 cases say a,b,c,d, I plan to seperate them and create seperate classes 
the 4 cases have something in common, I put them in an interface and create a base class that implement the interface.  now there are something in common between a&b, a&c, c&d, not sure how to make a good/clean implement

thanks

Comment: Can you give more concrete examples of what you're doing? It would help to make decisions on how to proceed.

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question at the moment because it's too vague. Please give a specific example.

Comment: Are you sure inheritance( "is a" ) is the right approach? Maybe "has a" is better suited? Again, more details would help.

Comment: sorry. I've 4 UDFs for Excel AddIn A,B,C,D, they are using web service to request data and plot data in excel. Each function uses different web service call (URL&payload). There are some optional parameters applied to all functions like sort order, show summary etc. Some options can only applied to A&B, A&C, C&D. I've one class to handle this where I use if/ switch statements. I wanna clean up codes, I extract an interface from the class call IFunc, and created a base class BaseFunc, I am thinking to create a class Func_A_B_Common inheriting from BaseFunc, Func_A,Func_B from Func_A_B_Common

Comment: Func_A_C_Common, Func_A need inherit from Func_A_B_Common & Func_A_C_Common, but C# is single-inheritance, also the same for function C,  so I am not sure how to handle this properly

Answer (score 2):

There are several options.

You could have c and d inherit from a, and d inherit from c.
You could create a base class for each pair a/b, a/c, and c/d.
You could duplicate functionality.
You could provide the functionality via a helper class (static methods might be an option).

It really depends on what functionality is being shared, and the intended usage of the classes.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the common things works and how they relate to and use private/protected data, but often composition can be a complement or alternative to inheritance.

Break out the common parts to helper classes that you use from the different implementations of a,b,c and d.

This is only possible if the implementation is not tightly coupled to the private data of each class.

Comment: Right now they are tightly coupled and entangled in one class. and I want seperate them out and also do not want to duplicate code in seperate classes. I just start to clean up and find out it is hard to de-couple

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule, you should only use inheritance if your objects are different kinds of the same object. If this is the case, then you can use inheritance to share implementation that's inherent in the definition of the base object.

If classes a,b,c and d aren't really different kinds of the same object then you can try encapsulating their common functionality in an internally referenced object.

```
public class a
{
    private CommonFunctionalityClass commonFunc;

    public a()
    {
        this.commonFunc = new CommonFunctionalityClass();
    }
}
```

When you want to do the common stuff, you just call your instance of commonFunc. You can do this same encapsulation for a/b, b/c, and c/d where you share functionality via a has a relationship using an internally referenced object. That way you don't duplicate code, but you can share functionality flexibly.

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface IABInterface
{
    //Whatever is common to A and B. It will have to be implemented in the classes
}

public interface IACInterface
{
    //Whatever is common to A and C. It will have to be implemented in the classes
}

public interface ICDInterface
{
    //Whatever is common to C and D. It will have to be implemented in the classes
}

public class ABCDBase
{
    //Whatever is common to all classes
}

public class A : ABCDBase, IABInterface, IACInterface
{
}

public class B : ABCDBase, IABInterface
{
}

public class C : ABCDBase, IACInterface, ICDInterface
{
}

public class D : ABCDBase, ICDInterface
{
}
```

You can create later in a static class extension methods for your interfaces to not duplicate the code for your methods in the Interfaces implementations (In other words, don't define methods in your interfaces, only properties). With refactoring can be really easy to implement the properties in your interfaces.
It would be nice to have extension properties. Hopefuly in the future.

**EDIT**

Like this:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static void IABMethod1(this IABInterface aOrBObject, arguments args)
    {
        //This will be available for any A or B object without duplicating any code
    }
}
```

Comment: @Arturo, thanks. in your proposal, both A, B have to implement IABInterface which is duplicate. I am thinking public class ABBase : ABCDBase, IABInterface{};  public classACBase: ABCDBase, IACInterface{}; then public class A need inherit from classABBase, ClassACBase which is not possible in C#, so I will try composition(has-a). thanks

Comment: That is not very clean, because you also would like to create `public class ACBase : ABCDBase : IACInterface { }` and you CANNOT inherit A like `public class A : ABBase, ACBase { }`

Comment: If you use Extension methods for your interfaces you run out of problems. This is the benefit of using interfaces in your case, and you don't duplicate any code.

Comment: @Arturo, thanks. I used extension but did not know I can do this way. Cool. Thanks, I'll give it a try

Comment: @Arturo, one more question, I have some private data which is common to A & B, To avoid duplicate, I am thinking to change it to public and put it in Interface IABBase, Is there a better way? thanks

Comment: By data you mean properties? If these are properties or fields than you would have to declare them in the classes, which of course is not great because that would duplicate some code. If you can create the private fields (or better `internal` to make them accessible in your interfaces extension methods) at the ABCDBase level can help  alot.

If you are talking about methods, you can also create private extension methods.

Comment: No, I mean private fields, which are used by A&B, not C or D, so I do not want to put them in ABCDBase.

Comment: If you dont want those fields in your base class, using this approach will force you to create them in each individual class.
It is not possible to completely hide them through interfaces.